# FOSUserBundle not working Validation

Tags: symfony, validation, fosuserbundle, type-hinting

I'm using symfony 3.3 and php 7.0 with the FOSUserBundle version 2.1.1 and I just realize that in the User Entity if you just add in the setters parameters the type hint like for example this... the validation will fail.

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use ...;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $firstName;

   /**
    * @return string
    */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }
    /**
    * @param string $firstName
    */
    public function setFirstName(string $firstName) <- IF YOU ADD THIS STRING AS THE PARAMETER THE VALIDATION FAILS
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
    }
}
```

So finally the line should be like this next:

```
public function setFirstName($firstName)
```

If anyone knows how to add the typehint without giving problems to the validation will be nice the hear news.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how Symfony Validator works by default: it first sets the value (`null` for instance), then the validation is performed, not the other way. Because your method does not accept `null` values, only strings:

```
public function setFirstName(string $firstName)
```

Most probably, you are encountering error `Exception: Argument 1 passed to setFirstName() must be of the type string, null given`.

To overcome this you either have to set empty data for the corresponding field to `''` or [detach your entities from the form component](https://stovepipe.systems/post/avoiding-entities-in-forms). Or you can force method to accept null values:

```
// php 7
public function setFirstName(string $firstName = null)
{
    $this->firstName = (string) $firstName;
}

// >= php7.1
public function setFirstName(?string $firstName)
```

I urge you to stop mixing entities with forms and validators. Your core domain should be free from such low level concerns (vide [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) from the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))). Also by the look of your setters I can tell you are moving towards the antipattern called [Anemic Domain Model](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the FOSUserBundle does not allow the typehint at the moment if you want to use the validation functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Your method setFirstName() in the User class must be compatible with FOSUserBundle/Model/UserInterface->setFirstName($username)

The interface has no typehint, so you can't add the typehint in your method...